# Pyspark - Filter RDD With Dates in Broadcast Dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a python dictionary that I broadcast which contains date filters by user.

```
nested_filter = {"user1":"2018-02-15"}
b_filter = sc.broadcast(nested_filter)
```

I want to use this broadcast variable to filter a larger RDD with rows less than the filter date.

```
rdd_set = sc.parallelize([("user1","2018-02-05"), ("user1","2018-02-20")])

rdd_set.filter(lambda fields: fields <= b_filter.value.items()).collect()
```

But it returns an empty RDD.

Could someone please point out what I am doing incorrectly? Also, do I need to convert the string dates to a date object?

The correct result should be:

```
[("user1","2018-02-05")]
```

Comment: Why is the broadcast variable a dictionary? Why isn't it just a single date? Do you want to use a different `date` for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the value returned by `b_filter.value.items()` inside your `filter` call is the same as:

```python
nested_filter.items()
#[('user1', '2018-02-15')]
```

So then your comparison becomes:

```python
("user1","2018-02-05") < [('user1', '2018-02-15')]
#False
```

Which is `False`. Assuming that `nested_filter` is a dictionary with just 1 item (as shown here), what you probably intended to do was compare to the first element of the list:

```python
("user1","2018-02-05") < nested_filter.items()[0]
#True
```

So to "fix" your code, you *could* do the following:

```python
rdd_set.filter(lambda fields: fields <= b_filter.value.items()[0]).collect()
#[('user1', '2018-02-05')]
```

But instead, what I think you actually want is the following:

```python
rdd_set.filter(lambda fields: fields[1] <= b_filter.value.get(fields[0])).collect()
#[('user1', '2018-02-05')]
```

This uses `fields[0]` to get the date from the `nested_filter` (or return `None` if it doesn't exist) and compares the value with `fields[1]`.

As you have noted, this comparison will happen lexicographically on the strings. This won't be a problem for you if your dates remain in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, but for other date formats you may need to convert to a `datetime` object.